# SpannableString no funciona

Tags: android

Hola buenos días tengo una duda con la clase SpannableString de android, soy muy nuevo con esta clase y además mis conocimientos relacionados a cuando algo funciona para una api o no o que api deberia escoger son limitados.

Tengo este trozo de código en mi método onCreate():

```
    String texto = "Texto para usar";

    Spannable timeSpannable = new SpannableString(texto.toUpperCase());

    boton.setText(timeSpannable);
```

Esto no funciona, para cerciorarme le he dado otro uso a la clase  Spannable y he probado este método que he encontrado en este mismo foro en inglés:

```
public static SpannableString highlight(String s, int k) {
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(s);
    ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, k, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);


    return ss;
}
```

Luego lo llamo en onCreate() de modo que el código de mi programa queda así:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Button boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ir);

    boton.setText("Texto para usar");

    boton.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);

    boton.setText(highlight(boton.getText().toString(),3));
}
```

Eso tampoco funciona, mi pregunta es ¿hay algo que este haciendo mal?, ¿hay algún tipo de restricción a la hora de usar la clase Spannable en algún Api en concreto, y ¿como debería modificar mi código para que funcione?

La api mínima de mi proyecto es la 15: iceCreamSandwich.

La api de mi móvil es la 22 que es donde pruebo la aplicación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Spannable`  tiene un problema con la función `allCaps`.

Eso, combinado al hecho de que desde Android 5.0 los botones traen por defecto `allCaps` activado, como parte del estándar [*Material Design*](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html#):

> Button text should be capitalized in languages that have
>   capitalization. For other languages, colored text on flat buttons
>   distinguishes them from normal text.

Provocará que los textos de `Spannable` no funcionen.

Encima, en tu código, conviertes el texto en mayúscula, lo cual no es necesario.

### Solución 1:

Quitar `AllCaps` del botón desde Java:

```
String texto = "Texto para usar";
Spannable timeSpannable = new SpannableString(texto);
boton.setAllCaps(false);
boton.setText(timeSpannable);
```

### Solución 2:

Quitar allCaps desde el layout del botón:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:allCaps="false" />
```

Prueba así y comenta si funciona.

Para más detalles puedes [ver esta respuesta de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29843714/5587982).

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, ha funcionado tu respuesta, ahora he conseguido justo lo que quería con el método hightlight coloreando solo una parte del texto del botón, de todos modos comentar que lo de UpperCase() ya lo sabía y lo había probado con lowercase() la primera vez y aun así no funciono, (ahora sí) gracias doy la respuesta por correcta y una pregunta más, la función allCaps que traen los botones por defecto ¿la traen los textView y los editText?

Comment: De nada. Ese problema, que yo sepa, es sólo con respecto a los botones. Edité la pregunta poniendo la fuente. Para los otros elementos que mencionas, _Material Design_ no los convierte a mayúsculas por defecto, sino que sólo convierte la primera letra en mayúscula: _The first letter of input text (and each sentence in a field) should be capitalized where appropriate._ [Ver fuente](https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-layout).

Comment: Muy bien, gracias por la ayuda!